# Why do Ubuntu Servers connect to likho.canonical.com:80?

Tags: networking, connection, traffic

We have some Ubuntu 12.0.3 servers in our network and I can see several denies per day on our physical firewall.

The Ubuntu servers are attempting to connect to 91.189.91.15 (likho.canonical.com) over port 80.

Can anyone tell me what this connection attempt is and should I allow the traffic or configure the server to stop making the connection attempt?

Comment: Why was the post edited - it kinda changed the meaning of my question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe in teaching people to fish so why don't you visit http://likho.canonical.com/? Port 80 is habitually web traffic so that's why I'm suggesting opening it in your browser.

You'll quickly see that `likho.canonical.com` is a repository. It's probably just a load-balancing thing (a round-robin A record to be precise) for the `archive.ubuntu.com` address. The domain you're seeing it the [reverse IP lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).

Therefore a connection from your server is probably a reflection of your server updating its local package records, and/or subsequently downloading updates.

#### How do we confirm `likho.canonical.com` is legitimate?

Well first let's prove that `likho.canonical.com` can be resolved from `archive.ubuntu.com`. Here's the trimmed `dig archive.ubuntu.com` output:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.92.176
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.92.177
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.92.200
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.92.201
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.92.202
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.91.13
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.91.14
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.91.15   <- This is likho.canonical.com
archive.ubuntu.com. 149 IN  A   91.189.92.156
```

And here are the lookups in both directions proving that `91.189.91.15` also resolves as `likho.canonical.com` (and vice versa):

```
$ host 91.189.91.15
15.91.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer likho.canonical.com.

$ dig likho.canonical.com +short
91.189.91.15
```

If you want further proof, you could do some TCPdumping to sniff out the traffic but I think that's crossing into an unneccessary high level of paranoia. If you can't trust your repos, you need to cut the Ethernet cable.

#### More fun with DNS and friends

If you want to play around, you can get the rest of the names of their servers that `archive.ubuntu.com` resolves to:

```
$ dig archive.ubuntu.com +short | xargs -I% host %
15.91.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer likho.canonical.com.
156.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer danava.canonical.com.
176.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer cursa.canonical.com.
177.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer zaurac.canonical.com.
200.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer obake.canonical.com.
201.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer urayuli.canonical.com.
202.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer sudice.canonical.com.
13.91.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ragana.canonical.com.
14.91.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer orobas.canonical.com.
```

See which has the lowest latency for you:

```
$ dig archive.ubuntu.com +short | xargs -I% ping -c1 % | awk '/time=/ {split($7, array, "="); print $4 "\t" array[2] "ms"}' | sort -n -r -t$'\t' -k 1
91.189.92.202:  19.8ms
91.189.92.201:  19.8ms
91.189.92.200:  19.4ms
91.189.92.177:  20.5ms
91.189.92.176:  19.6ms
91.189.92.156:  20.2ms
91.189.91.15:   97.4ms
91.189.91.14:   95.9ms
91.189.91.13:   96.4ms
```

And here's how you triangulate somebody's location to within three feet just using their latencies from known locations... Okay... Maybe not. It's probably possible to within a 50 miles (if you know the server locations and network links) but you'd need to know a lot more information than I certainly have.

Comment: I wish all answer on AU where styled like this :D In come the upvotes ;)

Comment: Hi Oli, Thanks for your reply. I was aware that it was a repository that the server was attempting to contact. You have said that "Therefore a connection from your server is probably a reflection of your server updating its local package records, and/or subsequently downloading updates."

Comment: Hi Oli, Thanks for your reply. I was aware that it was a repository that the server was attempting to contact and I wasn't concerned that this was malicious traffic.

You have said that "...your server updating its local package records, and/or subsequently downloading updates." and this is the area I am concerned with. If the server is attempting to update packages automatically I do not want it to. Are you saying that the server is running the equivalent of an apt-get update on a scheduled basis? If so is there a way to stop this automatic update of package information?

Comment: A default install of server won't do that. There are [a few methods of enabling this behaviour](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) so check that none of them are installed or that they're stopped from automatically upgrading. They all support *checking* without installing so I'd shoot for that.